# my app not working on new android version

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Hello all and thanks in advance for help,
i just finished  my APK file using react native and visual studio, the problem is when i install the app on old android version ( ex: android 5.1 or 6 ) it works and i use pm2 to monitor the app, but when i install it on new android version ( ex: 9 or 10 ) the application get installed but no data sent from it, i use register page and fill data and click on register and nothing happens, checked server log i find that no request was sent from the device. even if it works from the older android very perfect
any idea ?

Comment: Can you try running it on an emulated device with that older version ? Or can you connect your device and run the app and see if there are any errors and post more details.

Answer (score 0):

Android 9 and 10, all app using https by default.[Security with HTTPS and SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your app can connect with the server, can I know if it's an http or https server? If it's http, in your `AndroidManifext.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >  //add this attribute
... 
</application>
```